# In how many unique ways can you stack 10 blocks of different colors and varying amount's of each color block.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

## Statement of the problem:

Suppose Anna has 10 cubes with the following colours,

3 white blocks

2 red blocks

2 yellow blocks

1 blue

1 green

1 black

We wish to figure out how many unique stacks of blocks she can make (all blocks must be used).

## Attempt:

$$\frac{P_3^{10} \cdot P_2^{7} \cdot P_2^{5} \cdot P_1^{3} \cdot P_1^{2} \cdot P_1^{1}}{3! \cdot2! \cdot 2!}$$

$$
\text{Equivalently} \implies \frac{10!}{3! \cdot 2! \cdot 2!}
$$

$$
\frac{3628800}{24} = 151200 \hspace{0.5em}\text{unique sequences} 
$$

## Analysis:

I am taking the product of the permutation of each of the sets of colours of blocks and dividing by 24 since, the 3 white, 2 red and 2 yellow blocks are repeated in a particular sequence of blocks and therefore must be removed.

My question is, I am not entirely sure if this is correct and would like my work to be sorted through and corrected, an attempted explanation of the result would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct.

Here is another approach:  Choose three of the ten positions in the stack for the white blocks, two of the remaining seven positions in the stack for the red blocks, two of the remaining five positions in the stack for the yellow blocks, then arrange the blue, green, and black blocks in the remaining three positions, which can be done in
$$\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{2}3! = \frac{10!}{3!7!} \cdot \frac{7!}{5!2!} \cdot \frac{5!}{2!3!} \cdot 3! = \frac{10!}{3!2!2!1!1!1!}$$
ways.

The answer can also be expressed as the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)
$$\binom{10}{3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1} = \frac{10!}{3!2!2!1!1!1!}$$